# Tools for prototyping iPad applications

Tags: ipad, user-interface, prototyping

I would like to build a GUI prototype for an `iPad` application. The prototype can use static data (e.g. an xml file) but should look good and be fully functional, i.e. support user gestures, etc.

Obviously, I can program it in `Objective-C`. I wonder if I can use any other tool to build such a GUI easier. Does such a tool exist ?

Maybe I should use a GUI builder to build a "static" GUI and add some `Objective-C` code to make it react on user gestures. Does it make sense ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Antetype](http://www.antetype.com/)

It ships with various look and feels including ios and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Balsamiq: http://balsamiq.com/

Comment: I'm not sure balsamiq meets the "look good" criteria (obviously that's subjective, but I think the OP is looking for realism). Otherwise, Balsamiq rocks.

Comment: My personal take: I'm not a big fan of Balsamiq. It's expensive and there is a learning curve. It can get pretty complex to do even basic screens. I actually have several 8x11 inch hand-held whiteboards that I use to do my "prototyping". Draw > erase > draw is VERY fast, and when I'm done with each screen I capture it with a camera. Simple, fast and effective.